# Remove Duplicate words in lines

Tags: c#, regex, wpf, string

I've got a WPF application with TextBox and I need to create a function to format after I press a button from this input:

```
Perfume Soap Random52
Sample id: Random52
Key: 1324354657
Bubble Shampoo aRandom88
Sample id: aRandom88
Key: 1234567890
BathSoda Monkey 101
Sample id: Monkey 101
Key: 0192837465
```

to this output:

```
Perfume Soap
Bubble Shampoo
BathSoda
```

- it removes lines 2 & 3 and deletes duplicate words *including* original from line 1.
It looks simple, but I have trouble with that. I've got lost and have no idea how to continue. How can I make it work?

Comment: Will they always be in that format? Line 1 = Type + Id, Line 2 = Id, Line 3 = Key?

Comment: Is it sure that the input will always have this format exactly? Are this the transformations that will always be required to achieve the result? What will change on every new input? You need to analyse your input, define your expected result and then it will be easier to find the solution.

Comment: Everything in the first line except multiplied "Sample ID" is unique and must stay. I can get rid of the lines 2 & 3, I just need to remove sample id from line 1. It's always the same.

Comment: This explanation(example) does not match the output you gave! It is somehow unclear what you want to achieve.

Comment: @pasty What I want to achieve is get rid of line 2 and 3, also delete "sample id" from line 1. That's all.

Comment: Deleted my answer since the title of your question is different than your explanation.

Comment: Well, my main problem is to delete duplicate words in lines, so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the the input has the same structure every time, a possible solution using LINQ could look like this (without regex):

```
    var input = @"Perfume Soap Random52
Sample id: Random52
Key: 1324354657
Bubble Shampoo aRandom88
Sample id: aRandom88
Key: 1234567890
BathSoda Monkey 101
Sample id: Monkey 101
Key: 0192837465";

    var result = input
    // take all lines
    .Split('\n')
    // for each line
    .Select ((text, index) => 
    {
        // take only the desired lines
        if ((index == 0) || (index % 3) == 0 || (index % 6) == 0)
        {
            // split line on space
            var words = text.Split((char)32);
            // take desired words
            return String.Format("{0} {1}", words[0], (index != 0 && (index % 6) == 0) ? String.Empty : words[1]); 
        }

        return String.Empty;
    })
    // remove empty entries
    .Where (text => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(text));
    // join the lines again to one string again; separator is new line;
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\r\n", result.ToArray()));
```

The output is as desired:

```
Perfume Soap
Bubble Shampoo
BathSoda
```

Using regular expression for the word replacements is a good idea.

Comment: Thanks, but you have there {0,3,6}, but my list is longer. There are hundreds of '3-line' products.

Comment: how can I replace "new List<int> {0, 3, 6}" with "every third line in textbox"?

Comment: I tried and it works, except it cuts "Soap" from "Perfume Soap"

Comment: fixed it! try it again

Comment: Yep! Thanks a lot! You're my savior :) Now I need to learn this useful regular expressions. Gotta use them a lot...

Comment: That would be a good idea. My solution is very naive and fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var types = new List<string>();
    var previous = string.Empty;
    foreach (string line in text.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None))
        if (line.StartsWith("Sample id: "))
            types.Add(previous.Substring(0, previous.Length - line.Split(':')[1].Length));
        else
            previous = line;
```

Comment: After modification it shows what I wanted. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression can be used to extract the 3 lines that go together, then you can project the results.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<desc>.*)\nSample id: (?<id>.*)\nKey: (?<key>.*)");

var r = regex.Matches(content).Cast<Match>().Select(m => new {
    Description = m.Groups["desc"].Value.Replace(" " + m.Groups["id"].Value, ""),
    Id = m.Groups["id"].Value,
    Key = m.Groups["key"].Value });
```

Or to get just the first line for each group. Using the same regular expression:

```
var r = regex.Matches(content).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups["desc"].Value.Replace(" " + m.Groups["id"].Value, ""));
```

Comment: If your line endings are CRLF instead of just LF, replace all the `\n` with `\r\n`.

Comment: Works just fine. I made a mistake, because I had a tab in the input lines. Very elegant solution.

Answer (score -1):

Finally I found the method how to achieve what I wanted, so I will share it with others:

```
string input = "Perfume Soap Random52\n" +
               "Sample id: Random52\n" +
               "Key: 1324354657\n" +
               "Bubble Shampoo aRandom88\n" +
               "Sample id: aRandom88\n" +
               "Key: 1234567890\n" +
               "BathSoda Monkey 101\n" +
               "Sample id: Monkey 101\n" +
               "Key: 0192837465";

// split lines so each one is a different element of an Array
string[] split2 = input.Split('\n');

string output;

for (int i = 1; i < split2.Count(); i += 3) {
    output = split2[i - 1].Trim();

  // count number of words in first line (will use it later)
    string[] wordsList = output.Split(' ');
    int wordsCount = wordsList.Count();

  // combine lines 1 and 2 to begin duplicates removal process
    output += " " + split2[i].Trim();
    string[] split = output.Split(' ');

  // group elements together and filter duplicates
var singles = split.GroupBy(x = > x).Where(g = > g.Count() == 1).SelectMany(g = > g);
  // number of words removed from first line
    int cCount = (split.Count() - singles.Count()) / 2;
  // number of words remaining in first line after duplicate removal
    int wCount = wordsCount - cCount;

    output = string.Empty;

  // I don't know how to convert 'singles' type to array, so i did it my way
    foreach(string f in singles) {
        output += " " + f;
    }
  // output should now have all words inside without duplicates

    string[] oArray = output.Split(' '); // array full of output words
    output = string.Empty;

  // add only names to output, as I requested
    for (int c = 0; c <= wCount; c++)
    {
        output += oArray[c] + " ";
    }

    output = output.Trim(); // delete spaces around for cleaner looks
```

Output:

```
Perfume Soap
Bubble Shampoo
BathSoda
```